# Taxonomy publishing issue, when Category/Keyword in CM & broker databases are not in sync

Tags: 2013-sp1, broker, keyword, taxonomy

I am trying to publish a taxonmy, but following getting error :
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UIX_TAXFACETS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TAXFACETS'. The duplicate key value is (137, 268, 7).

I verified that 1 keyword exists in TAXFACETS table of Broker DB but it is not present in CM. I assume that it could be because of some DB refresh (that was done on this environment - don't have any traces of this).

Is there a way to resolve this, either by removing this unnessesary keyword from broker db or (may be) by forcing publishing for this taxonomy.

ver: 2013 SP1

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but could you try to manually build an unpublish package that contains an unpublish instruction for the offending category, and place this package in the incoming folder of your deployer?

Comment: @Harald, I have tried this already but no success.

Comment: When you say no success - I presume you mean it didn't remove the keyword? - is this keyword linked to any published content? If you've brought a populated Broker Database from somewhere else then it's not surprising you would get these kinds of issues and the best advice is (as per Shahid) to truncate and republish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is not a production environment, I would truncate the broker database and re-publish the whole content.

This is a much cleaner way to resolve such conflicts (rather than manipulating existing data)